# How can I choose specific list with Python?

Tags: python, list

```
loc = list(pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('img.png'))
```

It returns list like this:

```
[Box(left=1315, top=509, width=137, height=35), Box(left=455, top=511, width=137, height=35)]
```

My question is how can I choose just first list or just second list. Right now I know how to
select only random one with:

```
if loc
    loc = choice(loc)
```

Comment: That's _one_ list with two elements. Do you mean the first _element_ or the second _element_? Have you done a Python tutorial? Indexing into a list should definitely be included in any tutorial. For example, it's [covered in the official tutorial here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example shows just one list.However if you meant tuple or any iterator just go with loc[0] for first and loc[1] for next and so on.